# Android app that runs on devices with different architectures

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am building an android application (2.2 and later) that make use of **NDK** to perform some CPU-Intensive operations.

We need to be more carefull while developing NDK applications since it behave differently on different **CPU Architectures**.

And i want my application to run on **ARM, ARM-NEON,MIPS and x86 architectures**.

But [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#platform-compat) i read that,

> If you are deploying native libraries to x86 , your application must
>   target Android 2.3 or later.

Since i target **android 2.2 and later**, does that make any problems?

And how can i make my app run on all of the above said architectures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically if you can build with a Level 9 compatible NDK and get it packaged it should run on 2.2 ARM devices and 2.3 other architecture based devices (other architectures wasn't supported unless 2.3 so we don't have any devices like that).

Thing is the moment you add native libraries for specific architectures your app will be subject to filtering at [Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html).

> > An application that includes native libraries that target a specific CPU architecture (ARM EABI v7 or x86, for example) are visible only on devices that support that architecture.

So there is a chance that even your app works on a x86 device with Level 8 api, it may be filtered from market and x86 devices won't see it as available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about this but the Android developer spec seems to be pretty clear.

```
 [...] your application must target Android 2.3 or later
```

Maybe there might be some extension that makes it possible for you but I guess this is not the most common area to write Android extension libraries for. Try google for that.

Edit:

Take a look at these links:

http://www.nordichardware.com/Operating-systems/android-22-goes-native-x86-in-q3.html

http://www.android-x86.org/

Answer (score 1):

I had an app which targeted x86, MIPS, and ARM on Android 1.5 and higher, and it didn't cause any problems.

Note that there is no ARM-NEON architecture: armeabiv7a does not guarantee that NEON is supported.